# If Lingayats break from Hinduism would Lingayats become off-topic for the board?

Tags: discussion

It makes sense.  The rules seem clear about this.

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: Lingayats  worship Shiva as formless and even believe Basavanna as Nandeeshwara. Politically they may have new Religion, but still Lord Shiva is one of the  important principle deities of Hinduism. So, i am not sure if we should disallow their philosophy.

Comment: No because they will still be worshipping the Hindu God Lord Shiva. So, certain questions about them, their practices will still be considered as on-topic.

Comment: I think Sikhs and Jain worship Hindu gods and observe Hindu festivals.  So thats not a criterion @rickross .

Comment: Sikhs and Jains primarily worship Hindu Gods or the main deities are different for them? Sorry no idea about that.. but in case of the Lingayat then their object of worship is Lord Shiva only. @SK

Comment: I can say for certain that sikhs don't worship Hindu god's directly.

Comment: Moreover, this is why they should be on topic: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:DevelopmentofShaivism.jpg